# Casting int fraction to double

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to get a double (resulting from a fraction of two int) as a return value of my following function.

```
public static double getThresHold(int n) {

    int i, j;
    int openSites = 0;
    Percolation percolation = new Percolation(n);
    do {
        i = StdRandom.uniform(n) + 1;
        j = StdRandom.uniform(n) + 1;
        if ( !percolation.isOpen(i, j) ) {
            percolation.open(i, j);
            openSites++;
        }
    } while (!percolation.percolates());

    double threshold = openSites * 1.0 / n*n;
    return threshold;
}
```

but the result is always wrong, I get value such as:

```
200.0
240.0
260.0
```

The expected result should be between `0.6` and `0.5`

What is wrong with my code !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`openSites * 1.0 / n*n` is computed from left to right, so it is equivalent to `((openSites * 1.0) / n)*n`, which is equal to `openSites`.

You should use parentheses to force the order of operations, and instead of multiplying by 1.0 you can force floating point division by casting `openSites` to `double` :

```
double threshold = (double)openSites / (n*n);
```

This would also work but I find it less elegant :

```
double threshold = openSites * 1.0 / (n*n);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, you are awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
double threshold = openSites * 1.0 / (n*n);
```

Simply add parenthesis around the divisor. Casting to double is not necessary, as you multiply `openSites` with 1.0, which makes the expression `openSites * 1.0` an double.

So, your mistake is actually not a casting problem, but that you first divide `openSites * 1.0` by `n` and then multiply the result with `n`. So in your version you basically get `openSites * 1.0` as a result.